# How to setup PHPConsole with an API on another domain?

Tags: php, google-chrome

I just setup [php-console](https://github.com/barbushin/php-console) for my project, integrating it with [Lagger](https://github.com/barbushin/lagger). it's working fine as soon as I test my API calls directly with the URL to my API backend, but whenI go to my UI which is on another subdomain, the calls to the API are working of course but the PHPConsole is not being activated nor logging anything.

Is there a way to setup PHPConsole on server and/or frontend code to be able to log stuffs from the API calls into Chrome console?

API: `http://api.dev.mydomain.com`
UI: `http://dev.mydomain.com`

Calls to the API are done with `jQuery.ajax`.

Nothing logged in the UI Chrome console, but when trying individual calls to the API directly in another tab, the Chrome console does report log from php as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Now all you can do, is open `http://api.myserver.com/some.php` in browser tab. So PHP Console extension will enable headers listener for this domain and ask for authorization credentials(if required). Then you can work with this domain by AJAX until browser restart.

I have created new issue to implement sub-domain feature in PHP Console https://github.com/barbushin/php-console/issues/48 I'll do it in this month, when I'll have more free time :)

Comment: @Huafu I have reproduced the same case on my server, with different domains. And solution that I described works fine. Give me more technical details about your environment and I'll try to help.

Comment: app.myserver.com does not share cookie with api.myserver.com, it sends it in any http request as a URL parameter (`?sid=xyz`)

Comment: @Huafu That's right. So that's why you need to open all domains in browser tab to init PHP Console connection.